# Como fazer quando a linha da lista está imprimindo em mais de uma linha?

Tags: python, lista, print

Estou tentando imprimir minha lista composta pela junção de duas listas, mas quando rodo o programa o código está quebrando a linha e a imprimindo seu final em uma outra linha.

O código está dando esse resultado:

```
        VALUE      CLASS    TYPE      PUBLIC SYMBOL NAME              SIZE
    ======================================================================
    40000000H      DATA     DWORD     TimeWD
4
    40000004H      DATA     ---       GPIO_MASK
4
    40000008H      DATA     ---       GPIO1_MASK
4
```

E é assim que ele deveria imprimir:

```
        VALUE      CLASS    TYPE      PUBLIC SYMBOL NAME              SIZE
    ======================================================================
    40000000H      DATA     DWORD     TimeWD                          4
    40000004H      DATA     ---       GPIO_MASK                       4
    40000008H      DATA     ---       GPIO1_MASK                      4
```

Eu criei um arquivo a parte só para testar essa parte que está dando erro, mas quando mando rodar o erro não está acontecendo.

Aqui está o código:

```
lista1 = ['        8100498AH  DATA     BYTE      TEC2FUN', '        8100498BH  DATA     BYTE      EMREDE', '        8100498CH  DATA     BYTE      CAPSLOCK', '        8100498DH  DATA     BYTE      BALKEY', '        8100498EH  DATA     BYTE      PLUKEY', '        8100498FH  DATA     BYTE      ACTCOD']
lista2 = ['123', '234', '345', '456', '567', '678']


lista_arquivo = []
with open('ArquivoOrganizado.txt', 'w+') as arquivo_novo:
   
    title = '        VALUE      CLASS    TYPE      PUBLIC SYMBOL NAME              SIZE\n'
    div = '        ======================================================================\n'
    arquivo_novo.write(title) 
    arquivo_novo.write(div) 

    for (coluna1, coluna2) in zip(lista1, lista2):
        coluna_final = coluna1, '                          ', coluna2
        lista_final = ''.join(map(str, coluna_final))
        print(lista_final)
        lista_arquivo.append(str(lista_final)+'\n')
        '''print(lista_final)'''
        
 
    for items in lista_arquivo:
        arquivo_novo.write(str(items))
    print("File written successfully")

arquivo_novo.close()
```

Comment: Talvez esteja grande demais para.o prompt, não? E se você reduzir alguns espaços dessa linha?

Comment: redimensione o tamanho da janela do seu terminal para poder exibir os textos sem quebra de linha

Answer (score -3):

acho que voce nao precisa colocar o `+ '\n'` na linha `lista_arquivo.append(str(lista_final)+'\n')`, um novo print que vai ocorrer no proximo index do for já vai pular uma linha.